# Two smiling suns equals one smiling sun?

Tags: sql-server

How does SQL Server decide if two identifiers match?  No matter what order I arrange the following statements, SQL Server will happily create the first one, then refuse to create any of the others saying they already exist.

```
create database []
go
create database []
go
create database [   ]
go
create database []
go
create database []
go
create database []
go
create database []
go
```

Comment: pure guess, but weird chars are maybe filtered out? and then the result is an empty string that equals the rest?

Comment: Are you really trying to create a database with the name of a symbol? Don't do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does SQL Server decide if two identifiers match?

Database Names are compared using the [Server Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation?view=sql-server-2017). Inside a database the identifiers for Tables and other objects names are compared using the Database Collation.

> The server collation is specified during SQL Server installation.
>   Default server-level collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

For any two characters the collation determines which one is greater, or whether they are considered equal.  So is  > ,  < , or  = ?

```
select 'match'
where N'   ' = N'' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Matches, but

```
select 'match'
where N'   ' = N'' collate Latin1_General_Bin
```

doesn't.

Comment: Hmm ... I wonder how it works for passwords?  If I set my password to have a smiling sun in it, will SQL Server let someone log in using a cat face?

Comment: Passwords are stored and compared using hashes.